# How to get the caret position in ContentEditable elements with respect to the innerText?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contenteditable, caret, cursor-position

I am aware that there are a lot of existing questions about getting the caret position in `ContentEditable` elements. Almost all of those existing solutions provide the caret position with respect to the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
Some examples are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976125) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812022).

We are currently developing two WebExtensions to do autocorrection as the user types. For example, if the user types `:)`, it could autocorrect it to . For the autocorrection to work, it needs to get the caret position with respect to the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). The `textContent` can include whitespace characters and other differences that do not actually appear when the text is rendered, which breaks the autocorrect feature.

Our current method is partially adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258657, which provides the caret position with respect to the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). It clones the element, inserts the null character, determines the index and then removes the null character:

```js
// document.designMode is handled the same, see  https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/issues/54
if (target.isContentEditable || document.designMode === "on") { 
     target.focus(); 
     const _range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
     if (!_range.collapsed) { 
         return null; 
     } 
     const range = _range.cloneRange(); 
     const temp = document.createTextNode("\0"); 
     range.insertNode(temp); 
     const caretposition = target.innerText.indexOf("\0"); 
     temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp); 
     return caretposition; 
}
```

See [our original source code](https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/blob/09d806b3f731721236b774673d2b2f3db5a40d3f/src/content_scripts/autocorrect.js#L62-L74) for the full context. This method seems to work fine on 99% of websites, but breaks on ***Twitter***. The cursor is constantly reset to the beginning of the line as the user is typing, which scrambles the text (see [the corresponding issue](https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/issues/4) for more information). We are guessing that Twitter does not like the null character, but we tried with other nonprinting characters and had the same issue.

We are looking for another method to determine the caret position with respect to the `innerText` that will work on all websites, including on Twitter. It needs to support recent versions of both Firefox and Chrome, including Firefox ESR. It also needs to be performant, since it runs on every keypress.

---

Cross-posted on [Mozilla's Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-get-the-caret-position-in-contenteditable-elements-with-respect-to-the-innertext/91068?u=rugkx).

Answer (score 0):

### Steps

---

I get the `Selection` and `Range` from the `target` element

```
const selection = document.getSelection();
const range = document.createRange();
```

After checking if the `Range` is collapsed, your base code to insert the `null` character and getting the caret's position

```
const temp = document.createTextNode("\0");
selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(temp);
caretPosition = target.innerText.indexOf("\0");
temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
```

I then use this snippet to set the caret's position, which should be the fix to Twitter

```
range.setStart(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
range.collapse(false);

selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

```js
const target = document.getElementById('text');

target.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  let caretPosition = null;
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  
  if (range.collapsed) {
    const temp = document.createTextNode("\0");
    selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(temp);
    caretPosition = target.innerText.indexOf("\0");
    temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);

    range.setStart(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
    range.collapse(false);

    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ caretPosition }));
});
```

```css
#text {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<h3>ContentEditable Div</h3>
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">This text can be edited by the user.<br> Some <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic and <strong>bold</strong></em> text.</div>
```

Comment: [We have tried implementing it like this](https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/issues/62#issuecomment-916738896), but it does fail, i.e. it does not work. When this is used with a ContentEditable Div, there is an error for each keypress, because the caret position is wrong. [Tested here with the contenteditable.](https://rugk.github.io/unicodify/).

Comment: @rugk. Edited and fixed errors. Let me know if it's fine

Comment: [Here is another JSFiddle to reproduce the error](https://jsfiddle.net/tcomh4zb/), Now also adjusted [for your edit](https://jsfiddle.net/3mskc146/) and besides the fact that JsFiddle shows some linting errors in your code it also unfortunately seems to fail for a line break now, as it seems. @a.mola

Comment: Thanks, the caret position now works correctly and is correctly returned, however contrary to your assumptions, it still breaks (on) Twitter. Here is a [test branch/Pull Request](https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/pull/69) you can use in your browser to test it.

Comment: Alright, how do I use the [test branch/Pull Request](https://github.com/rugk/unicodify/pull/69) to test the way it works with Twitter @rugk

Comment: [That is described here](https://github.com/TinyWebEx/common/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding). The TL;DR: basically is: Clone with submodules and load the `manifest.json` into your browser as a browser extension.

Comment: @rugk; I haven't found a way to solve this; Any luck?